# Integrate trading view widgets with own data

Tags: tradingview-api

I have a requirement where I need to integrate the trading view widgets with the data received from globalfeed Api's. After long research I figured out that we can create charts using trading view and the data from the other services and api eg. LightWeightCharts. But I need tools along with charts that we get only in widgets.

So can we integrate widget with our own data?
Can we add tools in the LightWeightCharts?